# How to config a Cisco server ESXi with 3 VMs having only one IP address?

Tags: esxi

I’m changing  a server with a bare metal installation with  one ip to a new  cisco  sever with  `esxi` with  3 vm’s,  one  of them  is  going to be a  `nat router` to nat  the  traffic to the  other  2 vm’s, is there  a way to keep  using one  just ip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think so, you will  need  at least 2  one  for  esxi  virtual network to communicate with  your network and  one  for  your  nat  router vm  to distribute  the  traffic via `NAT`

In fact  if your server  has  `CIMC`  you  will  need another one  to have a remote access to `CIMC` if you need to recover the server, but it’s not mandatory  because  you can always  connect to  `CIMC` through  the console.